# Finding where the first vowel in a word occurs

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to write a program that translates English into PigLatin. I am currently trying to solve the part on where to locate the first vowel of the word that way the program can properly slice the word and rearrange it properly.

For example, the string "hello I am a guy" becomes "ellohay Iyay amyay ayay uygay". (At list I think my pig latin is correct, this is going off an example I created.

So for the word "what" becomes "atwhay". The program finds that the first vowel is in slot 2, then gives me that integer,2.

I was thinking of first comparing it to a string, vowels="aeiouy" and then go from there but I am stuck.
Here is what I have:

```
public static int indexOfFirstVowel(String word){
   int index=0;
   String vowels="aeiouy";
   return index;

}
```

In theory index will update to where the first vowel is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
final static String vowels = "aeiouy";
public static int indexOfFirstVowel(String word){
    String loweredWord = word.toLowerCase();

    for (int index = 0; index < loweredWord.length(); index++)
    {
        if (vowels.contains(String.valueOf(loweredWord.charAt(index))))
        {
            return index;
        }
    }

    // handle cases where a vowel is not found
    return -1;
}
```

This simply walks through the word by character, and checks each character to see if it exists within your vowels String.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using a mask representing the vowels in the ASCII table (not extented)?

It's not the simplest solution, but it's actually really fast because it use bitwise operations.

It returns `-1` if no vowel is found.

```
public static int indexOfFirstVowel(String aString) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++) {
        char c = aString.charAt(i);

        if ((c > 64) & ((0x110411101104111L & (1L << (c - 65))) > 0)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**edit:**

I forgot the extented ASCII table.

replace:

`if ((c > 64) & ((0x110411101104111L & (1L << (c - 65))) > 0))`

by

```
if ((c > 64) & (c <= 121) & ((0x110411101104111L & (1L << (c - 65))) > 0))
```

where 121 is the ascii code for `'y'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take each of the characters of a String with the method charAt()

```
public static int englishVowelIndexOf(String word){
    char[] vowels = {'a','e','o','i','u','y'};
    String wordLowered =  word.toLowerCase();
    for (int i=0; i < wordLowered.length(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j < vowels.length(); j++) {
           if (wordLowered.charAt(i) == vowels[j]){
              return i;
           }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You were a bit too slow unfortunately

Comment: convert the word to lower case to avoid problems: `word.toLowerCase().charAt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int indexOfFirstVowel(String word){
   int i;
    for(i=0; i<word.length();i++){  
     switch(word.charAt(i)){
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'y':
        return i;
     }
    }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't have breaks (which could not be a problem for some weird logic) but you haven't defined i's anywhere..

Comment: It's not a weird logic to check whether a string contain vowels or not .

Comment: @johnabrhm It is when it takes 12 times as much space as checking whether a character is contained within pre-existing String or char[]. Built-in methods like .contains() exist to prevent you from having to do stuff like this.

Comment: @furkle Space and time has always trade off . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff

Comment: it is weird logic this `index==-1` - you could just return i there and remove index entirely... Plus yours will do N comparisons assuming that internally it is not like a lookup table - in other implementations it will stop by the time it finds 'a'..

Comment: @MichailMichailidis How will be verify when there is no vowel in given string ?

Comment: you will return -1 at the end outside your for loop

Comment: @johnabrhm I didn't mean space as in memory, I meant space as in it's just a bunch of extra code.

Comment: @furkle Then use lambda expression that will take less space.

Comment: @johnabrhm What? How would a lambda expression fix the fact that you're using an overly long and elaborate way of dealing with a simple problem?

Comment: When you will write program using lambda expression , it automatically decreases code size . http://www.developer.com/java/start-using-java-lambda-expressions.html